# confusing syntax: "from smbus import SMBus"

Tags: python

I'm just learning Python and I'm confused by the syntax of the smbus importing and instancing(?). I am using a RasPi with Jesse.

In the examples below, each seems to refer to a function(?) named "SMBus" that specifies which of the hardware buses will be used for this communication.

My understanding of Python is that capitalization is significant
making smbus not the same as SMBus. My confusion is twofold:

1) I cannot find any reference to an smbus function "SMBus"

2) in the erazor-zone example code I would think only the SMBus function from smbus is being imported and that all the other functions in smbus are not available.

Can anyone explain where my thinking is going astray?

Thanks

JonRob

The two structures below are right from the internet:

**from  http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki:linux:python:smbus:doc**

```
from smbus import SMBus
b = SMBus(0)
b.read_byte_data(0x2f,0x58)
```

or

**from various github examples**

```
import smbus
self.bus = smbus.SMBus(0)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Briefly, it looks like `SMBus` is a _class_ within the `smbus` module.

Comment: Thanks TigerhawkT3..  succinct but right on target.   Cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 2):

The souce for this module is written in C.

I cannot connect to http://lm-sensors.org/ but search for `PyMethodDef` in the Debian package sources at https://sources.debian.net/src/i2c-tools/3.1.1-1/py-smbus/smbusmodule.c/

When you import a class, you obtain access to its methods, too; but you refer to them via the class or an object instance. So you don't want or need to import the `read_byte_data` method of `SMBus` because in normal use, you always refer to it as `b.read_byte_data` where `b` is an `SMBus` instance, like in your first example.

Just in case this is not completely clear, importing something in Python makes it available within your current namespace. Object-oriented programming encapsulates methods within an object; you use the object as a handle to access its methods, so you only import the object itself. One of the benefits is that your program's namespace (the number of things you access on a first-name basis) stays relatively clean, and it's clear and explicit - yet reasonably succinct - when you refer to things within an imported object's methods and properties.

Comment: Feel free to update this answer with a link to the authoritative source if/when it becomes available again.

Comment: To add a further bit of clarification WRT OO interfaces, the `SMBus()` function is a *constructor* which gets its name from the `SMBus` *class*.

Comment: Thanks tripleee,   I see it clearly now.   I think I was caught up in the documentation (or lack of).

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark is at accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unanswered. If you don't want to accept this particular answer, feel free to post one of your own and accept that.